# Linking data between 2 sheets based on non uniform data ranges

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, copy

I am trying to take a non uniform range of data on one sheet and link it up(cells will have "=Sheet1!A1", instead of hard coded values) to another worksheet within the same workbook.

I cant use just .UsedRange because I get a lot of empty cells in my selection which I don't want to link to another worksheet

Here is my code so far, but I get an error saying you can't use .copy with this kind of selection. Could someone please suggest a way around this. Thank you.

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
End With


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking to copy all ranges with values in them while leaving the blank ones?

Comment: How is the information arranged in the origin workbook? All in column A? multiple columns? one row, multiple rows? Could you give a small example of how the data is in the original sheet, and how you would like it to look in the finished product?

Comment: I dont know how to attach excel files here..couldnt find a way to attach it, so here is the next best thing....The data is in 5-6 columns going down 100 or so rows. There are multiple tables with table headings separated by blank rows. I want the blank rows/cells not to be linked to the new sheet.

Comment: So are you trying to merge tables with values only after a new series is created?

Comment: Not trying to merge tables. Just want to start pasting the links few rows lower, leaving cells blank.... I just actually got help with following code: [code] Sub test56()

    Dim area, myRng As Range
    Set myRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With myRng
        For i = 1 To .Areas.Count
            .Areas(i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet6").Select
            Range(.Areas(i).Cells(1, 1).Address).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
        Next
    End With
End Sub
     [/code]
Thank you for taking your time to look at my issues.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt more help.

Comment: you gave this issue your time, and I appreciate that. Thank you

Comment: You should always use error checkin with `SpecialCells` in case the range does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the `SpecialCells` ranges cell by cell, and write the links based on the source cell address, like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ShName As String
    Dim OldCalc As XlCalculation

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    OldCalc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    sh.Cells.Clear '<-- Optional
    ShName = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!"
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        sh.Range(cl.Address).Formula = ShName & cl.Address
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = OldCalc
End Sub
```

While looping over a range is not ideal (due to speed) it may be adequate in this case.

This `Sub` will error if the active sheet is empty: you may want to add an error handler for this case

Comment: Error Handling should always be used with `SpecialCells`.